# How to find out exception line number in R

Tags: r, logging, log4r

I am new to R language. I gone through exception handling frame work tutorials, but i can't able to find any options to print entire error stack trace , below is my code

```
getData<-function(a,b){
 c=NULL
 tryCatch({
     c=a+b
   },error=function(cond){
     fileConn<-file("output.txt")
     writeLines(as.character(cond), fileConn)
     close(fileConn)
   }
 )
 return(c)
}
```

In above code if any exception happens i need to write in a file by mentioning the line number where the error occurred, let's say i am getting  input to the method like below

```
getData(1,"vv")
```

It will throw exception like below, but I am not able to find the exact line number where error occurred , please help me to resolve this issue

> Error in a + b: non-numeric argument to binary operator